# How to Query referenced tables in JPA Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have 4 models:

Blueprint, that describes a single type of Item:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "BLUEPRINT_TAG", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "blueprint"))
private List<String> tags;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "blueprint", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<BlueprintProperty> properties;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "blueprint", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Item> items;

@Column(name = "width")
private Float width;

@Column(name = "height")
private Float height;

@Column(name = "imagePath")
private String imagePath;

@Column(name = "zPosition")
private long zPosition;
```

BlueprintProperty, that describes what information can be entered for each type of Item.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "blueprint")
@JsonIgnore
private Blueprint blueprint;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PropertyType type;

@Column(name = "data")
@Convert(converter = JpaJsonConverter.class)
private ObjectNode data;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private List<ItemProperty> itemProperties;
```

Then there's Item:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent")
//@Nullable
private Item parent;

@Column(name = "pos_x")
private Float posX;

@Column(name = "pos_y")
private Float posY;

@Column(name = "transformation")
private String transformation;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "blueprint")
private Blueprint blueprint;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Item> children;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ItemProperty> properties;
```

And finally, ItemProperty, that holds foreign keys referencing Item the specific property belongs to, and BlueprintProperty it's describing:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "item")
@JsonIgnore
private Item item;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "property")
@JsonIgnore
private BlueprintProperty property;

@Column(name = "value")
private String value;
```

Now, I'm not exactly happy with this setup, but that's what I have to work with and unless completely necessary I shouldn't change anything. What I'm trying to do is create a Query that takes a number of Item properties and returns all Items which properties match the query.

Using Query by example sounded promising, but I found out that [only SingularAttribute properties can currently be used for property matching.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.execution). So that killed that approach, and I don't think I can use native query, because a certain Item can have N properties, and you should be able to enter a query that searches by a single property, up to N properties.

Can someone suggest a way to perform the search I need and get a List of Items matching whose properties matched those entered as a result?

Comment: why dont you use `IN :ITEM_PROPERTY`? Pass in a list of item property to the query.

Comment: I recommend avoiding Query By Example as it does not work with many use cases and in general is very limiting.
With JPA, you could just do a join and put your restrictions there.

Comment: But can I do that if the user can submit a different amount of parameters in different searches? For instance, in one search they enter only "Model" property, but in the next, they enter "Model", "Manufacturer", and "Size"?

Comment: You could use a query object - which is a simple pojo really, holding all the search parameters that are theoretically possible.
When doing the actual query to the DB, you ask your query object whether parameter X is set and only do the restriction for this parameter if it is. If it is empty, you skip the restriction.

Comment: check the "In" keyword from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation, I am still not sure what your query means ("properties" match the parameters ...completely or partially), but if you want all Items, which has *any* property in the parameter list, that does it....and takes a variable length list of properties as input...if you want only the item which have *exactly* the properties from the parameter list...

Comment: It's pretty hard to give an example query, because the database is full of references, but I'll try. One Item can have many ItemProperties. ItemProperty consists of reference to the Item it belongs to, reference to the BlueprintProperty describing it, and Value which is the actual information describing that particular Item. The user should be able to search for an Item by entering 2 out of its 5 values, and he should get all items that match both of those 2, regardless of what the other 3 values are.